# Is it possible to demolish someone without using the boost?

Tags: rocket-league

In Rocket League, you can demolish (blow up) people by boosting into them, once you hear a "sonic boom".

You can hear a similar sound when, say, flipping forward a few times.

Can you demolish someone this way without needing the boost?

Comment: Internet search doesn't turn up much... From personal experience, it seems like if you aren't boosting (flipping) you slow down pretty quickly. It would be pretty impractical to rely on this... but I'll test this later if I remember.

Comment: Please don't confuse boosting with flipping though. Boost is the rocket, flip is the ... flip :P

Comment: I didn't. I compared when you aren't boosting to flipping. In case the comment was confusing at all.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. It can be read either way. Glad we agree that boosing =/= flipping :P

Comment: From what I can tell demolishing is not so much about the sonic boom, but relative speeds. If you hit an opponent that's considerably slower than you, you will demolish him. If you both are going fast, sonic boom won't help either. Only a theory though.

Comment: @atticae Certainly a possibility to consider. However, I feel like I often manage to demolish people while chasing a ball in the same direction (low relative speed), and failing to demolish people during head-on collision at sub-boom speeds (high relative speed).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it does work. Just tested it myself. However, your window to demolish opponents seems a bit smaller. I had to hit them in mid-flip just after going supersonic. Otherwise I slowed down too much after the flip was finished.